# how to add +4 in an array address in MIPS

Tags: mips

i am trying to use a loop to store say '2' integers to an array. So i thought i will use a loop that goes on 2 times, and each times it store a number in Array1 + cngAdd , where i will initialize cngAdd to 0 at beginning, and increase it by 4 at the end of loop. so at second iteration of loop the address is added by 4.

So to read the input i do:

```
li $t7, 2
li $t6, 1

intReadStore:   

li  $v0, 5
syscall
sw $v0, Array1 + cngAdd

lw $t0, cngAdd
li $t0, $t0, 4
sw $t0, cngAdd

li $t6, $t6, 1
ble $t6, $t7, intReadStore
```

But in qtspim i get an error in this statement : sw $v0, Array1 + cngAdd

Could you please tell what should i use instead of cngAdd (so that i change the address by + 4 , using some variable , or by even using any general purpose integer register, without hardcoding "4")?

Note: my data are:

```
.data
 cngAdd    .word    0
 Array1    .space   2
```

my Array1 is of 2 integers here but i want to do it for 'n'. however for this question 2 is sufficient i think.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the base address in a register, and increase it once per loop iteration:

```
la $a3,Array1    # Put the address of Array1 in register $a3

intReadStore:   

li  $v0, 5
syscall
sw $v0, ($a3)    # Store the value at the currently pointed to element of Array1

addiu $a3,$a3,4  # Point to the next word in Array1
```

You may need to save/restore `$a3` when you do the `syscall`, since the value of `$a3` might not be preserved.

---

By the way, the `size` argument for `.space` is in *bytes*  as far as I know. So for 2 words you need to reserve 8 bytes of space.